# Bash function to output a line that contains a searched string, with caveats

Tags: bash

TL;DR: grep for a string in a file and output the match that is closest before a given line number.

I'm trying to write a bash command line function to find a line within a file that contains a given string.
I don't know bash enough to write it; though I've been trying.

The input to the function is:

1. The string to search.
2. The file to search.
3. A line number; the match for the string will be somewhere before this line.

The match will definetly exist within the file.

There may be multiple matches for the string within the file, but the line that I'm interested in is the closest
to the line number, in reserve. For example, if the passed line number is 100, and there were matches on
lines 5, 30, 77, then I'm interested in the match at line 77.

I want the output of the function to be the value of the line (the whole string)
contains the searched string. Example

```
some foo value
some bar value
some zee value
```

and the search was for 'bar'. I want the output to be:

```
some bar value
```

Comment: After verbalizing the question, I thought of an answer: `head -n $line $file | grep $str - | tail -n 1`

Comment: `head | grep | tail` is almost always better spelled `awk`.  In this case: `awk 'NR==max{exit} match($0, str) {a=$0} END {print a}' str="$str" max="$line" "$file"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
head -n $num $file | tac | grep -m 1 $string
```

1. head -n to get first n lines
2. tac will reverse the order of lines returned by head to put the closest match at the top
3. grep -m 1 will return  only the first line matching the string